# Descendant child CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a selector class called `.logo` for example
and the usage in html might resemble to this.

```
<div class="nav">
    <a class="logo"></a>
</div>
```

I see a lot of them styled in descendant child format as follows

```
.nav .logo { 
   width: .. 
   height: .. 
}
```

What would be the benefit over a single selector declaration like the following?

```
.logo {
   width: ..
   height: ..
}
```

I understand that html mark up will be much tidier with hierarchy structure application and also it will help scalability with media query adjustment but with this particular logo example that I see many implemented in this way, I am not too certain of the benefit.

**Added**

I understand which is more specific to take precedence. I guess I'm after opinions more on re-usability.

Comment: *I guess I'm after opinions more on re-usability.* Totally depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.nav .logo` is more specific than using `.logo`

Also the latter one will be applied to all the element having `.logo` in the document where `.nav .logo` will be applied to element having `.logo` which is nested inside element having class `.nav`.

You should avoid nesting styles if it's not necessary, as it not only affects performance but also you will endup writing more and more specific rules to override the previous.

In this case, it is likely to use `.logo` as a website has a single logo, but again, say what if the designer is designing a client page where he has a class `.logo` on each of his client logo directory list? So in this case he will use `.nav .logo` for his site logo and say he has other `.logo` wrapped inside an element say `.client_list` so he will use `.client_list .logo` in this case.

Comment: Everything in CSS is specificity and Cascade, if you know what to place at what situation, you are the master. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

The usage of descendant is not really good idea. That's because you tight your .logo class with specific container. What will happen if you later change the markup to:

```
<div class="nav">
</div>
<a class="logo"></a>
```

The other benefit is that you are able to reuse the same styles somewhere else. Instead of writing another .logo class for the footer for example. I'll suggest to read a little bit more about [OOCSS](https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki).

If you have a logo in the header and in the footer you may end up with the following styles:

```
.logo {
   background: url('...') no-repeat;
}
.logo-header {
   background-size: 100px 50px;
}
.logo-footer {
   background-size: 70px 40px;
}
```

Then use the following markup:

```
<header>
   <a class="logo logo-header"></a>
</header>
<footer>
   <a class="logo logo-footer"></a>
</footer>
```

In general you share some styles between the header and the footer, but still have a specific css for both places. I found it much better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can have more elements with `class="logo"`, this is a way to target only those elements that are inside a `.nav` element. Leaving the other `.logo`s alone.

Of course if you only want to target one specific `a` in particular, you may want to give that `a` an `id` to make it unique.

Comment: No, please don't use IDs. Targeting an element with id is normally leading to problems. Yes, it has a better specificity, but it tights the styles to that specific element.